# Как сделать чтобы hover элементов списка не изменял подсписок?

Tags: html, css, hover

При наведении на элемент списка - все элементы списка изменяются вместе с его элементами подсписка. Хочу чтобы `hover` изменял элементы подсписка отдельно.

```css
#work-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
#work-menu li:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#work-menu ol {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
#work-menu ol:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="work-menu">
  <h3>Основные виды работ:</h3>
  <li><a href="1.html">Отделка фасадов камнем</a>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <a href="otdelka-fasadov-mramorom.html"></a>Отделка фасадов мрамором</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="2.html">Декоративная штукатурка</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="3.html">Оформление трафаретами</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="4.html">Плиты</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="5.html">Декорирование фасада</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все проблемы от того, что вы отлавливаете событие наведения на `li`. Поскольку `ol` у вас расположен внутри `li`, то наведение на него и его дочерние `li`, заставляет сработать `:hover` и на родительский элемент `li`.

Уточните селектор до `a`, тогда добьетесь нужного эффекта. Вот ваш код с минимальными изменениями:

```css
#work-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

#work-menu ol {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
#work-menu a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="work-menu">
  <h3>Основные виды работ:</h3>
  <li><a href="1.html">Отделка фасадов камнем</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="otdelka-fasadov-mramorom.html">Отделка фасадов мрамором</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="2.html">Декоративная штукатурка</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="3.html">Оформление трафаретами</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="4.html">Плиты</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="5.html">Декорирование фасада</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо исправить CSS свойство `#work-menu ol` на `#work-menu ol li`:

```css
#work-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
#work-menu li:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#work-menu ol li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
#work-menu ol li:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="work-menu">
  <h3>Основные виды работ:</h3>
  <li><a href="1.html">Отделка фасадов камнем</a>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <a href="otdelka-fasadov-mramorom.html"></a>Отделка фасадов мрамором</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="2.html">Декоративная штукатурка</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="3.html">Оформление трафаретами</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="4.html">Плиты</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="5.html">Декорирование фасада</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Я скопировал Ваш код - ничего не изменилось